# XQuery: how to use dates and compare them

Tags: xml, date, xquery

I have a sort of database made of some file.xml of this form:

```
<bursar>
  <invoice>
     <number>...</number>
     <date>21/6/2014</date>
     <object>...</object>
     <receiver>...</receiver>
     <operator>...</operatore>         
  </invoice>

  <many other invoices>

</bursar>
```

I should use XQuery to get the invoices included between two dates: "from" date to "to" date. How can I express this with XQuery? How can I compare dates? Because I guess they are saved in the file.xml as strings so I don't know how to express the concept of "begin date" and "end date"...
This is what I'm thinking to do

```
for $v in doc('invoices.xml')//bursar/invoice
where $v/date >= "begin date" and $v/date <= "end date"
return $v
```

How can I convert those strings to real dates so that they can be compared? They are in the form of dd/mm/yyyy ... Thanks

Comment: Relevant XKCD: http://xkcd.com/1179/ (Had you used a sensible date format in your XML to begin with then you'd have no problem now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say whether you need an XQuery 1.0 solution, or can use XQuery 3.0.

### XQuery 1.0

XQuery 1.0 misses quite some formatting functions, which would make this much easier. The [FunctX function library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) offers quite a bunch of them, so let's take advantage of them instead of writing new code. In the end, it boils down to decompose the date and use the [FunctX function `functx:date(...)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_mmddyyyy-to-date.html) (and its dependencies) to compose the date:

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";

declare function functx:date
  ( $year as xs:anyAtomicType ,
    $month as xs:anyAtomicType ,
    $day as xs:anyAtomicType )  as xs:date {

   xs:date(
     concat(
       functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($year),4),'-',
       functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($month),2),'-',
       functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($day),2)))
 } ;

declare function functx:pad-integer-to-length
  ( $integerToPad as xs:anyAtomicType? ,
    $length as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

   if ($length < string-length(string($integerToPad)))
   then error(xs:QName('functx:Integer_Longer_Than_Length'))
   else concat
         (functx:repeat-string(
            '0',$length - string-length(string($integerToPad))),
          string($integerToPad))
 } ;

 declare function functx:repeat-string
  ( $stringToRepeat as xs:string? ,
    $count as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

   string-join((for $i in 1 to $count return $stringToRepeat),
                        '')
 } ;

let $date := tokenize("21/6/2014", "/")
return functx:date($date[3], $date[2], $date[1])
```

It is definitely possible writing that code in less lines, but it's tedious rewriting functions already out there.

### XQuery 3.0

With XQuery 3.0, you can do all the decomposing, formatting and date construction with few built-in statements:

```
string-join(
  reverse(tokenize("21/6/2014", "/")) ! format-number(. cast as xs:integer, "00"),
  '-'
) cast as xs:date
```

In short, this tokenizes to the individual components, reverses their order, formats it to have at least two digits per component (required for casting to an `xs:date`), recombines them to the expected pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` and finally casts to an `xs:date`.

Comment: Thanks! XQuery 3.0 is perfect! I didn't know there were differences also for dates in XQuery 3.0... thanks

Comment: I mainly took use of the much improved number formatting capabilities here (and the application operator `!`). By writing your own `format-number` and replacing the `!`, you'd be able to use the same patterns with XQuery 1.0.

Comment: Another format to store dates is yyyymmdd. I prefer this as it is easy to sort dates stored in the above format, and too without use of much functions. Hope this might be helpful.